# Book recommendation: commentaries on aggadah?

Tags: talmud-gemara, jewish-books, agada-stories-legends

Shalom. Does anyone know of a good book/set that collects mefarshim on aggadic portions of the talmud? **I am specifically looking for works that summarize or collect various opinions or commentaries, as opposed to individual commentaries.** I want to be able to see in one place how a bunch of different mefarshim have explained an aggadah.

For example, I know there are some collections of the Ein Yaakov that have commentaries. If someone has an edition of the Ein Yaakov with a bunch of commentaries they recommend I'd appreciate that as well. However, the Ein Yaakov does not contain all aggadah and also sometimes has different girsaot and therefore different pshat.

Comment: You can try Biurei Aggados from the Gras perspective and interptation of aggados. O believe there is an English themed book based off it called Juggler and the king.

Comment: Thank you @sam. I do have that work (in Hebrew) which is really on two big passages plus a few more. And of course there is Maharsha, Beniyahu, etc. What I'm looking for (which may not exist) is a single book I can take when I'm learning an aggada out and see a bunch of explanations different people have given on it.

Comment: I mean the artscroll ein yaakov is actually really good and has a lot of interpretations for some things. Read also “the crowns on the letters” by Ari Kahn if you want fresh and novel interpretations of some aggadata

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: https://www.sefer.org.il/items/3733735-%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%94%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%97%D7%96-%D7%9C-%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%91-%D7%9B%D7%91-%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91-%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%9A-%D7%92%D7%91%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%93

Comment: Chiddushei aggados maharsha?

Comment: It is not comprehensive but if you fancy something in English, Rabbi Immanuel Bernstein has a sefer entitled, *Aggadah: Sages, Stories & Secrets*

Comment: Agados Maharit, you will not go wrong. The Satmar Rov was a gadol with no equal in his generation.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions. Some of these are interesting commentaries. But more what I was looking for was a secondary work that collects or digests different perushim. For example I have seen ein yaakovs printed with a bunch of perushim on the side. I'm wondering if there are other works like that that either collect commentaries or digest them.

Answer (score 3):

By far the most comprehensive analysis of the Aggadah sections of the Talmud that I have used is a series called
**שיעורים בהגדות חז"ל**
written by a רב חנוך גבהרד about 20 years ago.

Seems it came in 2 versions.

[image: Image of books]

The contact details are printed as:

> רח' משך חכמה 35
> קרית ספר 71919
> Phone: 08-9744666

The set seems to be out of print, but you can possibly find individual volumes in Seforim stores.

Comment: Thank you. That does look promising. Can you tell me a little more about what it does or includes? For example, based on the title is it like longer essays on certain topics or is it more trying to be encyclopedic of mefarshim? Is it just on the Ein Yaakov or does he bring other agadot?

Comment: It's based on shiurim the author gave on the Ein Yaakov. It starts by translating the text to spoken Hebrew, and then giving some background information and then explaining the Aggadah. This can sometimes go on for pages. His aim is to get every Aggadic passage to teach us something we can apply nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

As a teacher in Mesivta, I've been using עין יעקב המבואר, it is fantastic, it includes Maharsha, Ben Yehoyada, Maharal and a few other authentic pirushim.

https://seforimplace.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=6134

Comment: @Harel13 is "**N**aharal" a typo?